# Reading specific value from a text file extensi .job

Tags: php, mysql

i have question, for get specific contain of file. i already get all data from many file .job extension, now i want to get data just in JobID rows so i can get all data JobID rows from many file .job, i want the output be "**115518024**" and more like the example. sorry my english. thanks

CODE GET DATA

```
foreach (glob("C://xampp/htdocs/LogMesinMutoh/*.job") as $file) { 
$file_handle = fopen($file, "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $line = fgets($file_handle);
    echo $line;
}
fclose($file_handle);
}
```

DATA FILE

```
[JobSetting]
File=D:\Shared\print\2017\september\26\Printing Ira\Cat Pattern EKA SITOMPUL 55X55.tif
PrintSetup=VJ-1624W_MURIM_HP100_4PASS.tps
RaPInfoFile=VJ-1624
JobID=115518024
WorkType=3
SourceSizeX=549.980530
SourceSizeY=549.980530
DestSizeX=549.980530
DestSizeY=549.980530
```

Comment: If the data file is short like the one you showed us, you can use `file_get_contents` to read the content of the whole file, the use **regex** to get the data you need.

Comment: file_get_contents for many files it work ?

Comment: Yup, just change the code in the loop from openning a file handler and reading line by line to using file_get_contents, you'll have a string with the full text, then use regex to get the JobID

Comment: i will try. if i have problem. i will ask later. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $str is a file content

```
$str = "File=D:\Shared\print\2017\september\26\Printing Ira\Cat
Pattern EKA SITOMPUL 55X55.tif
PrintSetup=VJ-1624W_MURIM_HP100_4PASS.tps RaPInfoFile=VJ-1624
JobID=115518024 WorkType=3 SourceSizeX=549.980530
SourceSizeY=549.980530 DestSizeX=549.980530 DestSizeY=549.980530";


$regex = '/JobID=(.*)/';

preg_match($regex, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

You will get your output at **$matches[1]**

Comment: i just want get the value from jobid. without Jobid=.

Comment: You will get JobID without label at $matches[1]

Comment: it works, but when i try to PrintSetup=.. the value just VJ.. what should i do ? add the regex ?

Comment: replace old pattern with
$regex = '/PrintSetup=(.*)/';
it will work for all,  special characters not consider in old pattern

Comment: can i ask again. how to get value 2017 september 26 in this string.. File=D:\Shared\print\2017\september\26\printing\baryun - cetak transferpaper.tif